# nested fetch using deferred in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, fetch, jquery-deferred, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to run multiple fetchs to populate a collection which is a property of a model.
I receive all information I want to get, but as soon as my function is done every group has the same members (the members which have been fetched the last).
I placed two console.log statements in the code to se where the informations are right the last and when they get wrong. Nevertheless, I have no idea what I can do to store the information write.

```
    var dfr = $.Deferred();
    var that = this;
    that.get('groups').fetch({
        data: $.param({ match_id: that.get('match_id')}),
        success: function(response) {
            response.each(function(obj, i) {
                 $deferreds[i] = $.Deferred();

                 obj.loadMembers(loadRatings).done(function(){
                    $deferreds[i].resolve();
                     console.log(obj.get("group_members")) // HERE ALL GROUPS ARE RIGHT
                });
            });

            $.when.apply(null,$deferreds).then(function(){
                console.log(that.get("groups")) // HERE ALL GROUPS HAVE THE SAME MEMBERS
                dfr.resolve();
            });
        },
        error: function (model, response) {
          dfr.fail("could not load users");
        }
    })
    return dfr;
```

Comment: shouldn't you assign the `obj` values to the actual collection?

Comment: You are looping over your response, inside the response you have multiple objects, on every iteration each object performs some action and the next object performs the same action again, so by the time you reach your last object, it overwrites anything that the previous objects did ? How do you add models to the collection that your receive from the ajax call ?